# ADF Test using rollapply

Tags: r, quantitative-finance

I am wondering if there is a way to do ADF Test on a given interval. Below is an example of me calculating the mean for every 20 samples:

```
rollapply(data, 20, FUN = mean)
```

I want to use the same logic and run ADF test for every 20 samples. Therefore I used the following code:

```
n = 24
test <- rollapply(spreadClose, n, FUN = adf.test)
```

Note: adf.test() is from library called "tseries".

Could anyone explain why this is not working? I am getting the following error.

> Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
>     length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

I would really appreciate any feedbacks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following codes and it started working:

```
adftest <- function(x)
{
    adfPvalue <-  adf.test(x)$p.value
    adfPvalue
}

PValue <- function(x) {
    Pvalue <- rollapply(x, N, adftest)
    Pvalue
}

PValue(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
library(zoo)
library(tseries)
z <- zoo(rnorm(100), as.Date(1:100))
rollapplyr(z, 20, adf.test)
```

Comment: I tried and I got the following error message:
Error in zoo(rval, index(x)[i]) : 
  “x” : attempt to define invalid zoo object

Comment: what is your `rval`? Is it a column or a vector?

Comment: whats a rval? I am pretty new to this.

Comment: This is from your error message: `Error in zoo(rval, index(x)[i])`. What is `rval`?